# HTML - <textarea> tag difficulties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, textarea

Problems:

1. If textarea length exceeds its limit, and we give the input in the middle of the text than it start the truncate character from the end. But i don't want that textarea behavior.

   What I want is, I only want to allow textarea that takes only 4000 character. and if user try to enter extra character than it should not be allowed.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cursorPosition=0;
    var enterKey_code=0;
    var maxlength=4000;
    var flag=0;
    
    function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
        if (input.setSelectionRange) {
            input.focus();
            input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        }
        else if (input.createTextRange) {
            var range = input.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
            range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
            range.select();
        }
    }

    function setCaretToPos (input, pos) {
        setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
    }
    
    $('#MaxChar').text(maxlength);
    
    function countChar(key_event){
        var text_value = $('#Comments').val();
        var cursorPosition = $('#Comments').prop("selectionStart");
        var len=text_value.length;       

        if (len > maxlength) {                       
            flag=1;
            $('#Comments').val(text_value.substring(0, maxlength));     
        }
        
        $('#CurrentChar').html($('#Comments').val().length);
    }

    $('#Comments').keyup(function (key_event) {
            countChar(key_event);
            
            if(flag==1)
            {
                var c=$('#Comments');
                setCaretToPos(c[0], cursorPosition+1);
                flag=0;
            }     
    });

     $('#Comments').keydown(function (key_event) {
            cursorPosition = $('#Comments').prop("selectionStart");
            countChar(key_event);
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <label id="CurrentChar">0</label> / <label id="MaxChar">0</label>
  <br />
  <textarea rows="20" cols="40" id="Comments"></textarea> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Please try this fiddle in chrome browser.....you will understand my problem jsfiddle.net/j2pz0tjg/2

Comment: no problem occurs if you try ONLY the  `<textarea maxlength='4000' rows="20" cols="40" id="Comments"></textarea>` part without any JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Try simple HTML solution with `maxlength`

> `maxlength` Declares an upper bound on the number of characters the
>   user can input. Normally the UI ignores attempts by the user to type
>   in additional characters beyond this limit.

```html
<textarea maxlength="4000"></textarea>
```

There is an alternate with jQuery plugin [jQuery Max Length](http://keith-wood.name/maxlength.html)

Comment: @Divyesh It is compatible with all major browsers. check here: http://caniuse.com/#search=maxlength

Comment: i don't allow user to enter or add content an textarea if maxlength exceed

Comment: Did u comment all javascript code and try? This attribute doesn't require any javascript.

Comment: @ Vicky in chrome : if i past the text that contain text with new lines and now if i remove last character it will not allow me to enter again at the last.

Comment: @ Vicky Gonsalves : Please try this fiddle in chrome browser.....you will understand my problem 

https://jsfiddle.net/j2pz0tjg/2/

Comment: Its because you have 3 linebreaks in the data.. remove 3 or more characters and try entering again..

Comment: I show this link before a day,....
But how can i say to user that please do not break the line while past the text ...??

Comment: So don't you count whitespaces as well?

Comment: I have made my own logic same as your above link....but If textarea length exceeds its limit, and we give the input in the middle of the text than it start the truncate character from the end. But i don't want this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101576/discussion-between-divyesh-and-vicky-gonsalves).

Answer (score 2):

simply use this:-

```
 <textarea maxlength='4000'  rows="20" cols="40" id="Comments"></textarea>
```

it automatically stops when user types 4000 characters. That means though user type more than 4000 characters, they don't get insert into the text area.

If you further wants to prompt an warning message to user when the limit exceeds, just add the below simple JavaScript piece of code.

```
$(function() {  
    $("textarea[maxlength]").bind('input propertychange', function() {  
        var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxlength');  
        if ($(this).val().length >= maxLength) {  
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
            $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, maxLength));  
        }  
    })  
});
```

Comment: `$(this).val().length > maxLength` this will never execute.. since maxlength attribute will never let you cross the limit

Comment: corrected it as `$(this).val().length >= maxLength` .

Comment: I don't want use any message box ......simply i don't want user to enter character ...

Comment: Then use only this part. `<textarea maxlength='4000'  rows="20" cols="40" id="Comments"></textarea> `

Comment: @ Iresha Rubasinghe to use only <textarea maxlength=4000> it not work in chrome browser ..

Comment: @IreshaRubasinghe Let OP generate his own logic.. Even after showing him the proof, OP says it doesn't work in chrome!

Comment: yes @Vicky Gonsalves :D it works fine in chrome TOO!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$('#Comments').keydown(function (key_event) {
                    var text_value = $('#Comments').val();
                    var len=text_value.length;
                    if (len > maxlength) {      
                        key_event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    cursorPosition = $('#Comments').prop("selectionStart");
                    countChar(key_event);
            });
```

Comment: You can ignore these keys (ctrl + c, ...). I think it's ok

Answer (score 1):

On input check if the value in the textbox is >= 4000, then disable the textbox element.

Check this link for more info about textarea and the disabled attribute. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_disabled.asp